# Installing Linaro on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gcc, linaro

I am following [this guide](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC) to install Linaro on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine (64-bit Duo core).  Unlike the guide, I want to have the latest Linaro version.  Thus, these are the commands I use:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib

wget -c https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz --no-check-certificate

tar xf gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz

export CC=`pwd`/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-

{CC}gcc --version
```

It fails at the last line, complaining:

```
{CC}gcc: command not found
```

Can somebody enlighten me?  What have I done wrong?  This process previously failed when I used Linaro 6.4.1 as in the guide.  Thank you so much in advance.

As N0rbert pointed out, I put the `$` in there. The output is:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Linaro is nowhere to be found.  How does that `export` command work, and why is not not doing what it should?

Comment: Your forgot `$` sign - should be `${CC}`. It is a variable.

Comment: @N0rbert, I added the `$` sign.  I still dont get the expected output.

Comment: OK, somebody told me to use `echo ${CC}` and it worked afterwards.  No clue why.

Answer (score 0):

Download Linaro and add path at the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file.

> PATH=$PATH:"Path_to_Linaro_Extract_Directory/bin"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OxEUQKW_QEk